# Timeout awaiting DeviceInformation Win10

Tags: uwp

I have two static methods:

```
public class RenderDevice
        public static async Task<List<DeviceInformation>> GetDeviceNames()
        {
            DeviceInformationCollection dir = await  DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(MediaDevice.GetAudioRenderSelector());
            return dir.AsEnumerable().ToList();
        }
}
```

and:

```
public class CaptureDevice
        public static async Task<List<DeviceInformation>> GetCaptureDeviceNames()
        {
            DeviceInformationCollection dir = await  DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(MediaDevice.GetAudioCaptureSelector());
            return dir.AsEnumerable().ToList();
        }
```

and using :

```
var renderDevices = RenderDevice.GetDeviceNames();
    renderDevices.Wait();
    var captureDevices = CaptureDevice.GetDeviceNames();
    captureDevices.Wait();
```

I got a timeout sometimes on first `.Wait()` and sometimes on second `.wait()`
Looks like a problem with `DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync` or have I done something wrong?

Comment: Yes, using `Wait()` is wrong in most cases, just `await` the call

Comment: What Igor says is right. If you can't use await on this place, you can write an async method with void, like: private async void RenderDev(); This method doesn't need an await.